# How to query for all users that belong to a trip given a list of trips?

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables:

`trips [id, name, ...]`

`users [id, first_name, last_name, ... ]`

`trips_users [trip_id, user_id]`

I already have a filtered list of trips but now I am trying to get the users that are on each trip.

When I search for just one trip and its corresponding users, I use a INNER JOIN and that's not so bad.

But when I search for a list of trips and get a filtered list, I am having some trouble figuring out how I can write a query to get just the users that are on the trips I got previously.

So,

I am first doing something like this -

```
SELECT id, name, ...
FROM trips
WHERE <some filters>
```

This gives me a list of trips.  Now, I need to associate a list of users that were on that trip, so how can I do that in one go?

Or do I need to iterate through my list of trips and just run the inner join query on each one?

I tried using a RIGHT JOIN but that gives me hella rows which is bad right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do a inner join with trip_users table. Since this table has details of all trips and their corresponding users.

```
select tu.user_id
from trips t 
inner join trips_users tu 
on t.id = tu.trip_id 
where trip_id = <Filters>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution:

```
select trips.id as tripid, trips.name as tripname, user.id as userid, first_name, last_name
from trips
join trips_users on trips_users.trip_id=trips.id
join users on users.id=trips_users.user_id
where <some filter>
```